# Button click in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, buttonclick

**The button should open a new activity and should display the information of only that particular card whose button has been clicked**

I have 6 cards in RecyclerView also I am fetching data from Firebase

My RecyclerView code :

```
  public class index extends AppCompatActivity  {

  private Toolbar toolbar;
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private DatabaseReference myRef;

  private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.index);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/Doctor");

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Listitem,ListItemHolder> adapter = new 
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Listitem, ListItemHolder>(
            Listitem.class,
            R.layout.list_item,
            ListItemHolder.class,
            myRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ListItemHolder ItemHolder, 
Listitem model, int position) {
            ItemHolder.setDocName(model.getDocName());
            ItemHolder.setSpeciality(model.getSpeciality());
            ItemHolder.setAddress(model.getAddress());
            ItemHolder.setExperience(model.getExperience());
            ItemHolder.setFees(model.getFees());

            ItemHolder.bookButton.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Intent i = new Intent(index.this, Booking.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


  }
    public static class ListItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
 implements View.OnClickListener  {
        TextView head,desc,desc1,desc2,desc3;
        Button bookButton;

        public ListItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            head = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
            desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
            desc1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc1);
            desc2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc2);
            desc3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc3);

            this.bookButton = (Button) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
        }

        public void setDocName(String DocName) {
            head.setText(DocName);
        }

        public void setSpeciality(String Speciality) {
            desc.setText(Speciality);
        }

        public void setAddress(String Address) {
            desc1.setText(Address);
        }

        public void setExperience(String Experience) {
            desc2.setText(Experience);
        }

        public void setFees(String Fees) {
            desc3.setText(Fees);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }
}
```

CardLayout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/greyshade"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

     <LinearLayout
        android:padding="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewHead"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Heading"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            />
    <TextView

    android:id="@+id/textViewDesc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/Desc"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDesc1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Desc"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDesc2"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/Desc"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDesc3"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:maxLines="1"

            android:text="@string/Desc"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/bookButton"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Book"
                android:textColor="@color/textbutton"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/bookbutton"
                android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/textViewHead"
android:text="@string/Heading"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/black"/>

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewDesc1"
    android:text="@string/Desc"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Logout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Your button doesn't open the activity? The info you want to display is not shown in the new activity? Please elaborate.

Comment: By applying the intent the button opens the new activity but does not show the information @antonis_st

Comment: @VismayPatil wait I'm posting the answer

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, yes.

Comment: @VismayPatil check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to make your model class serializable...

```
public class Listitem implements Serializable { ..... }
```

Change your Intent like this..

```
Intent i = new Intent(index.this, Booking.class);
i.putExtra("data",model);
startActivity(i);
```

On `Booking.class` Actvity  `onCreate()` method

```
Listitem model;

Intent extra = getIntent();
if (extra != null) {
     model = (Listitem) extra.getSerializableExtra("data");
}
textview.setText(model.getDocName);
............
............
```

Comment: It is opening the activity but not displaying the data

Comment: after getting the model class.. display your data.. by `model.getDocName` etc etc..

Comment: `ItemHolder.bookButton.setOnClickListener(new 
       View.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Intent i = new Intent(index.this, Booking.class);
                        i.putExtra("DocName", model.getDocName());
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                  });`

Comment: @VismayPatil my code sending entire model class data to other activity

Comment: Success ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to take a look at my project repository: [Android Firebase Clickable Cards](https://github.com/ashwindmk/Android-Firebase-Recycler-Card-Detail)

It does exactly what you described.

However if you are just having trouble in sending an object from one activity to another, then the best method is to use Parcelables.

First make your object parcelable:

```
public class Listitem implements Parcelable {

    private String docName, address, ...;

    public Listitem() {
    }

    public Listitem(String name, String address) {
        this.docName = name;
        this.address = address;
        ...
    }

    public String getDocName() {
        return docName;
    }

    public void setDocName(String name) {
        this.docName = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.docName);
        dest.writeString(this.address);
        ...
    }

    protected Listitem(Parcel in) {
        this.docName = in.readString();
        this.address = in.readString();
        ...
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Listitem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Listitem>() {
        @Override
        public Listitem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Listitem(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Listitem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Listitem[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Now to send object Listitem, just add it to intent:

```
intent.putExtra("listitem", listitem);
```

To retreive the object from Booking class:

```
Listitem listitem = (Listitem) getIntent().getParcelable("listitem");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do few changes in your code to get the result you want. If you also want the position of the view than you need **getAdapterPosition()** to get the position of the current **CardView** you have selected.

So your **ViewHolder** class should be like-

```
public static class ListItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
 implements View.OnClickListener  {
    TextView head,desc,desc1,desc2,desc3;
    Button bookButton;

    public ListItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        head = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
        desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
        desc1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc1);
        desc2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc2);
        desc3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc3);

        this.bookButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
        bookButton.setOnClickListener(this);  // change number 1
    }

    public void setDocName(String DocName) {
        head.setText(DocName);
    }

    public void setSpeciality(String Speciality) {
        desc.setText(Speciality);
    }

    public void setAddress(String Address) {
        desc1.setText(Address);
    }

    public void setExperience(String Experience) {
        desc2.setText(Experience);
    }

    public void setFees(String Fees) {
        desc3.setText(Fees);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();  // change number 2 if you need position for further work.
        switch(view.getId()){
           case R.id.bookButton:

             // do your other code here 

            break:
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And for receiving data on other Activity. you have to make your model class **Serializable** as answered by @Abhishek Singh.

Answer (score 0):

```
ItemHolder.bookButton.setTag(model);
```

And inside onClcik

```
Listitem model= (Listitem) v.getTag();
```

Then pass the required detail from model and put into Bundle, add it to the intent you are starting

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in the `intent` the things you want to show in the new activity. So your code should be like this.

```
`Intent i = new Intent(index.this, Booking.class);
 i.putExtra("docName", model.getDocName());
 i.putExtra("spaecialty", model.getSpeciality());
 i.putExtra("address", model.getAddress());
 i.putExtra("experience", model.getExperience());
 i.putExtra("fees", model.getFees());
 startActivity(i);`
```

and in your new activity do something like this

`String docName = getIntent().getStringExtra("docName")` etc. Notice that the "extra type" should match the type of extra you send.